# Windows Backup doesn't show Hard Drive

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, backup, external-hard-drive, time-machine

I am trying to get the Windows Backup working because the program that was delivered together with my Seagate Backup Drive is really stupid. I want to make incremental backups every hour. Something like Time Machine.

The problem is that I can't select the hard drive as backup drive. It lists my 2 secondary drives but I want a backup of those too.

Is there a way to make the backup on the Seagate drive? (or is there a good alternative for Incremental backups with the ability to rebuild the disk?)

I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: Is the drive formatted?

Comment: Yes, as NTFS. My other drives too.